# installation of ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, cd-image

I have created several iso s from the ubuntu download page.I have made a couple 64 bits as well as 32.Everytime I burn this iso and install onto my computer I pretty much on ly get the option to run it beside windows.I am trying to get it to replace windows completely but that option isnt there.I have used infrarecorder and the other one it recommended on the site as well.When I put the cd in I have the option to run wubi installer or view files.When I open the view files tab it seems that all files are there I think.I ve tried this with cd and dvd to burn.Am I doing something wrong in the burn phase?I ve burned iso images before and they have always worked.

Comment: Are you running the CD from within Windows? If so try booting from the CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your "burn phase", you can't change the ISO content..so if on my installation I got the option to install Ubuntu o my entire HD, you'll have the same option...

32 and 64 bits have a different installation setup but both, I have tested, offers a option to install side by side with other OS or install overwriting current OS and there is a red label giving some kind of alert.

There is no possible way your ISO is different then the rest of us, if you downloaded it from [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: @Gerep.....I greatly appreciate your input and I agree with you on that completely.There is no way that if we downloaded this from the same place the iso can be different.Now on that note-I ve seen several questions on askubuntu where someone asked why they didnt have the option to install alongside windows.My issue is I dont see where I can remove windows and use ubuntu as only operating system.If its on there do you have instructions on how to get to it?And if we all downloaded from the same place can you explain to me why the others dont have the option to run along windows?

Comment: @Gerep.....as far as 64 and 32,I came from windows but im not completely a noob to hardware,software,etc.If you can maybe throw something past the obvious my way very much appreciated

Comment: @robert I made some searches and yes..you are right but I bet the problem is with your other OS partition...what is it?

Comment: @robert what I meant with 32/64 bit was about the screens...the 32 bit has a more friendly screens.., it was not my intention to judge  your knowledge, sorry for the misunderstanding =)

Comment: no I didn't take it wrong.As far as my knowledge,lol,in ubuntu it s a hit and miss for me.Hardware wise and windows I m good.If my comment seemed snappy I apologize as well.I m running windows vista 32 bit home premium.I did pick up on your answer though and figured I d hit you up for more detail.I do have an option above run along windows that says try it or full installation.I think what i ve done wrong is I need to uninstall my dual boot,set my bios to boot from cd and go for the first option and that might get it.Lol as far as my knowledge over here feel I m lost lol

Comment: I am running 32 bit but my install only recognizes 3 gigs of ram so I ve been told to go ahead and install the 64 bit.I ve checked my hardware and am probably going to try it.If it doesnt work I m ordering a new motherboard and cpu setup for my computer.I do appreciate all of your help.

Comment: Yes..I tried 64bit and gave up...problems with video and wireless. I have 1GB unused =)

Comment: ah gotcha on the video.I installed a 64 bit version on my fathers computer.He has issues with video as well but I dont with the 32 bit.Lol wish I had my full 4 gigs but I m not complaining.I was so bored of windows,then installed ubuntu and wow.I ve noticed on the windows side it shows the full 4 gigs but checking further in actually sharing 1 and showing 3 so.I m starting to think it s mainly my motherboard/processor setup.I ordered some new hardware from tigerdirect.I appreciate your input on the 64 bit.

Comment: I'm gonna buy some new hardware too but in Brazil things are really expensive hehe...glad to help Robert